# Predict race position (data provided)

Tags: r, machine-learning, mixed-model, predictive-models, hierarchical-bayesian

I have data from race competitions consisting of race time for a competitor, their position in the race, an independent variable `x` and raceid. I'm looking for a way to predict the outcome in a new race. Not just the winner, but the whole ranking. This is what the data looks like:

```
df <- data.frame(                                      
competitor = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "D"),     
time = c(54.2, 48.3, 49.1, 105.2, 116.2, 112.5, 117.3),
position = c(3,1,2,1,3,2,4),                           
x = c(4, 6, 2, 3, 7, 5, 2),                            
race = c("race1", "race1", "race1",                    
"race2", "race2", "race2", "race2")                    
)                                                      

#>   competitor  time position x  race
#> 1          A  54.2        3 4 race1
#> 2          B  48.3        1 6 race1
#> 3          C  49.1        2 2 race1
#> 4          A 105.2        1 3 race2
#> 5          B 116.2        3 7 race2
#> 6          C 112.5        2 5 race2
#> 7          D 117.3        4 2 race2
```

I can't model the time because the races differ in length and elevation. I rather not model with position as dependent variable because then I would assume that the distance is equal between the observations when it isn't.

One idea I had was to restructure the data such that each competitor is "competing" against every other competitor. The data would then have to be restructured to look something like this for the first race:

```
df_wide <- data.frame(                       
competitor = c("A", "B", "A", "C", "B", "C"),
opponent = c("B", "A", "C", "A", "C", "B"),  
time = c(54.2,48.3, 54.2, 49.1, 48.3, 49.1), 
x = c(3,1,3,2,1,2),                          
win = c(0,1,0,1,1,0),                        
race = c("race1"))                           

#>   competitor opponent time x win  race
#> 1          A        B 54.2 3   0 race1
#> 2          B        A 48.3 1   1 race1
#> 3          A        C 54.2 3   0 race1
#> 4          C        A 49.1 2   1 race1
#> 5          B        C 48.3 1   1 race1
#> 6          C        B 49.1 2   0 race1
```

Then I suppose I could model the probability that A would win over B in a new race and thus predict position.

The data input for the prediction would be something like this:

```
new_race <- data.frame(competitor = c("A", "B", "E"),  
                       x = c(6, 8, 10))                                       

#>   competitor  x
#> 1          A  6
#> 2          B  8
#> 3          E 10
```

How would you approach this problem? Any models you would look into? Know of any examples? Pitfalls? My initial thought was some kind of hierarchical model.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing for F1 results on my blog. Please check it out: http://f1-predictor.com. I have found that the 2nd approach (comparing all drivers with each other) gave me better results. Of course, it's more complex and need a lot of thinking on how to convert the pairwise probabilities to a final ranking. I'm planning to post details on these topics in the future.

Comment: Ah, cool, that is pretty much what I am trying to do but for alpine skiing. Would be great to hear more about your project and how you model the data. Are you using R as well?

Comment: I'm using python for this project although I'm comfortable with R as well. I'm happy to help you in detail. You can find my email through blog -> linkedin -> email. Feel free to send me any questions.